# Getting a syntax error in Python and not sure why

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I'm trying to create a program that asks for actual value of a piece of property and display the assessment value and property tax. The county collects property taxes on the assessment value of property, which is `60%` of the property's actual value. The property tax is  `$.72` for each `$100` of the assessment value.

Any suggestions on what I did wrong?

```
#Create a program that asks for th actual value of a piece of property
# and display tge assessnebt value and property tax.
ASSESSED_VALUE = .60
PROPERTY_TAX=.72 *(ASSESSED_VALUE/ 100.00)

def main():
property_value = float(input('Enter property value: '))

def calcu_value(property_value)
assessed_value = property_value *assessed_value
property_tax = property_value * property_tax
# display totals of  
def display_calcu
print(property_value)
    format ('total_sales tax, '.2f'))
print(property_tax)
    format ('total_sales tax, '.2f'))

# Call the main function
main()
```

Comment: What is the **exact text** of the error you're getting? Also, your indentation is all screwed up. Please fix it.

Comment: The bad indentation? The missing half of the function definition? The missing quotes and colons?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few syntax problems.  Simplifying a bit (and I'm just taking a quick run at this), try this:

```
#Create a program that asks for th actual value of a piece of property
# and display tge assessnebt value and property tax.
ASSESSED_VALUE = .60
PROPERTY_TAX=.72 *(ASSESSED_VALUE/ 100.00)

def main():
    property_value = float(input('Enter property value: '))
    assessed_value = property_value * ASSESSED_VALUE
    property_tax = property_value * PROPERTY_TAX

    print("Property value: {}".format(property_value))
    print("Property tax: {}".format(property_tax))
    print("Assessed value: {}".format(assessed_value))

# Call the main function
main()
```

That runs without errors, at least.